# xsl:call-template and xsl:with-param in exsl:document

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, exslt

I try to submit parameters to a template called in a exsl:document node, but the template always retains the default parameters, I don’t understand.

Could someone help me?

```
<xsl:template 
    match="/office:document/office:body/office:spreadsheet/table:table">
```

I defined here variables from the main input file, including a list of input files.

Then for each input file:

```
    <xsl:for-each select="document($SourceFilePath)">
```

I create an output file:

```
        <exsl:document href="{$SourceFilePath}.result.fodt">

            <xsl:call-template name="remove-meta-user-defined"/>
```

Here is the problem:

```
            <xsl:call-template name="add-meta-user-defined">
                <xsl:with-param
                    name="add-element"
                    select="'a dog'"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
            <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>

        </exsl:document>

    </xsl:for-each>


</xsl:template>
```

Templates are defined as follows:

```
<xsl:template
    match="/office:document/office:meta/meta:document-statistic"
    name="add-meta-user-defined"
    mode="OutputTemplate">
    <xsl:param
        name="add-element"
        select="'a cat'"/>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="OutputTemplate"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:element name="meta:user-defined">
        <xsl:value-of select="$add-element"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template
    match="node()|@*"
    name="identity"
    mode="OutputTemplate">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" mode="OutputTemplate"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] including the input and the expected output (outputs, in this case).

Comment: By creating my minimal example, I discovered that my problem was quite different. Thank you for the answer! This is good advice for beginners. If I do not find the solution to this new problem, I'll ask a new question, being careful to be clear enough.